How to get the top most level object in a nested structure in Angular component
I am trying to build a query builder using Angular similar to JQuery builder.I am facing an issue with respect to emitting the data.
When I click the addGroup, addRule buttons then the new group is getting added to the array at the specified level. Now I want the entire object structure including the one which got pushed. How to get that from HTML to component ?
For example, If the Initial structure is :
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "price",
      "field": "price",
      "type": "double",
      "input": "number",
      "operator": "less",
      "value": 10.25
    },
   
  ],
  "valid": true
}

And I have added the newGroup now, so the latest structure is:
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "price",
      "field": "price",
      "type": "double",
      "input": "number",
      "operator": "less",
      "value": 10.25
    },
    {
      "condition": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "category",
          "field": "category",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "select",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "category",
          "field": "category",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "select",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "valid": true
}

I want this entire object to be available in component in addGroup method.There can be n number of nested levels and I want the entire object.
Working Code:text

what is the problem you are facing ?

Whenever I keep adding the new groups, this.group is not having the complete structure of the object, it only has the array at which new groups are pushed. In the stackblitz, If you add 2 nested groups and then click the print button on the extreme bottom. it gives the complete object. I want that in the addGroup method.

Why not using this.json?

We can use a service and store this entire object reference in one of the service properties, which we can access from anywhere within the querybuilder!
query.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class QueryService {
  entireObject: any;
  constructor() {}
}

app.component.ts
...
constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.queryService.entireObject = this.json;
}
...

rule-group.component.ts
 ...
 constructor(private queryService: QueryService) {}
 ...

 ...
 addGroup(index: number) {
    const newGroup = {
      condition: 'AND',
      rules: [
        {
          field: 'rule',
          operator: 'op',
          value: 'value',
        },
      ],
      valid: true,
    };
    if (!this.group.rules) {
      this.group.rules = [];
    }
    this.group.rules.push(newGroup);
    // I want to emit the entire object structure not just the one which is added now. How to get the entire top level object from HTML.
    console.log(this.queryService.entireObject);
  }
  ...

